# Getting UnAuthorized 403 Error in Postman Read or Patch on Azure FHIR API

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, unauthorized

I'm using Azure FHIR API, Created and FHIR API, Registered an Client Application and added Azure Health Care APIS as well data FHIR contributor role for my user.

Trying to access this FHIR API via postman, I'm able to generate bearer token via client credentials, On passing this valid credentials to access FHIR I'm getting below error in Postman:

```json
{
    "resourceType": "OperationOutcome",
    "id": "7fb05b3205cc7047f4f5365a8aabe325",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2024-01-17T19:54:52.1235183+00:00"
    },
    "issue": [
        {
            "severity": "error",
            "code": "forbidden",
            "diagnostics": "Authorization failed."
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Postman Screenshot]

I can make the Postman call for metadata to retrieve `capabilitystatement`, but I can't read or patch any other FHIR resource.

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of Postman

Comment: see attached postman screen shot

Answer (score 0):

I have deployed all the resources needed for FHIR instance using this [Doc](https://github.com/microsoft/dicom-server/blob/main/docs/quickstarts/deploy-dicom-cast.md#deployment-1).

In order to access the resources, you need to grant access to fhir instance -> Access Control (IAM) -> **FHIR Data Contributor** -> fhir container instance.

[image]

After granting the permission, generate the bearer token. Here I am trying to read Patient's data.

```
GET https://{fhir_instance_name}.azurehealthcareapis.com/Patient
```

[image]